# time() in C language

Tags: c, time

I have tried the function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  time_t seconds;

  seconds = time (NULL);
  printf ("%ld hours since January 1, 1970", seconds/3600);

  return 0;
}
```

It is useful but it returns the time in number of seconds since 1970. In my case, I would like to obtain a result with more precision, to distinguish two events happening in the same second. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Use `gettimeofday(3)`.  It allows you to get the time in microseconds.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <sys/time.h>

 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
   struct timeval tv = { 0 };

   gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);

   printf("sec: %ld usec: %ld\n", tv.tv_sec, tv.tv_usec);
   return 0;
 }
```

or with `clock_gettime()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  struct timespec ts = { 0 };

  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);

  printf("sec: %ld nsec: %ld\n", ts.tv_sec, ts.tv_nsec);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [clock_gettime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) . It gives additional info in nanoseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Basic Standard C does not describe any calendar time functions with a resolution better than 1 second.

You have to use extensions.

For POSIX, try <s>[`gettimeofday()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gettimeofday.html) *(obsolescent)*</s> [`clock_gettime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_gettime.html).
For Windows, apparently, you can use [`GetSystemTime()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).